# User Validation Unsuccessful

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am a Snowflake trial user and I have an issue with a network policy blocking access. I am trying to submit a support request but the User Validation step is unsuccessful.
This is the message I get:
*Your request to Snowflake support through the user validation request flow in the community was unsuccessful. We were not able to map your user to the requested account.*

I have tried twice now without success - what other options do I have?

Answer (score 2):

I am sure you might have already seen the below article, May I ask you to review it again with special focus on point 4, with details on the right-hand side of the screenshot:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Submit-a-Support-Case-in-Snowflake-Lodge

Thanks, FK

Comment: Yes I have seen this. I have verified that the details I entered are correct.

Comment: Last email I received was 5AM UTC

Comment: Thanks @johnmcp. Could you please send an email with your Snowflake Account URL & email address your are using to Support@snowlfake.com

Comment: Thanks @FKayani - I have just sent an email now.

Comment: @johnmcp, email received and the respective team will respond back to you. Thank you.

Comment: My email ticket was closed immediately. Response was "Unfortunately, access to the support portal is restricted to on-demand or capacity customers only". I replied but I have not had any response since. I also contacted sales and also no response there! I guess Snowflake have enough customers already...

Comment: @johnmcp, I have double-checked and trial account users cannot be enabled for the support portal but you are always welcome to send the questions/queries using the above email address. Snowflake would be happy to assist - Thanks